# A plumber replaced my vacuum break after it was damaged by ice. My sprinkler system still doesn't work. What to do next?

Tags: plumbing, water, sprinkler-system

Last week, I had a plumber come to my house because the vacuum break in my sprinkler system froze and broke.  This came as a surprise to me because we have always had the system properly winterise.

I had a service call from a plumber who said that the problem is that the shut-off valve upstream from the vacuum break leaked, allowing water to enter the winterised system so and then freeze.  He replaced the valve and the vacuum break and gave me a bill for 1030 USD for parts and labor.

After the service was done, we turned on the sprinkler system, and we saw that water gushed out of all the sprinkler heads regardless of the operation of the control panel.

The plumber said that he is not a sprinkler expert and the best thing to do would be to call a sprinkler service company for a service call.

Before I make another potentially very expensive service call, I wanted to ask here what I might do to try to fix the problem.

Again, the vacuum break is fixed, but once the water valves are opened, the water gushes from sprinkler heads all around the yard regardless of the control panel, even when the control panel is set to "OFF".

Comment: WOW!  $1030 for a service call, a new valve and a new vacuum breaker?  That seems extreme especially following that up with "I don't know what I'm doing here."  But he sure knew how to bill you!

Cut your losses and get a qualified irrigation servicer to investigate and fix your problem.

Comment: How on earth did you pay him that much money and not make sure everything was running properly before he left. Really confused!

Comment: @Sickest, it was already clear that the vacuum breaker was broken as it leaked copiously.  The plumber demonstrated how the shut-off valve was leaking and replaced both.